# Calculate probability table with exponentially increasing dimensions

Tags: r, statistics, bigdata

The goal here is to calculate the expected outcomes and scoring table of a game.

The game outcomes can be described in terms of a weighted dice roll:

- We can set the input weights and bonuses
- Then we roll N times
- Then we apply score modifiers to the outcome table
- Then we calculate the expected score of the set of N rolls.

  ```
  [roll: 1, weight: 0.24, score: 2],
  [roll: 2, weight: 0.11, score: 4],
  …
  [roll: 19, weight: 0.05, score: 7],
  [roll: 20, weight: 0.03, score: 20],
  ```

example bonus: min_set_score = rolls_per_set * 6.2

if we roll the die twice, we can manually generate the result table:

```
    [rolls: [1,1], weight: 0.24 * 0.24, score: 2 + 2]
    [rolls: [1,2], weight: 0.24 * 0.11, score: 2 + 4]
```

…etc
then [1,1] and [1,2] would actually be adjusted to 6.2.

How would we calculate the result table for 50, 100, 500 rolls?  50 rolls causes 20^50 outcomes, and can no longer be calculated by our naive implementation in a reasonable time frame.

Is this something that can be done with a better library? a more suitable language or technology?

This does not need to be done in real time, we would like to use the results to inform our decisions about how the game elements should affect the weights and bonuses.

Comment: Does the order of the rolls matter? Even if order doesn't matter, 20^50 / 20! is about 10^46, so you would need around 10^35 Terabyte hard drives to store the result. So, assuming you're not planning on buying AWS and Google to combine their computational resources for the next few years, what do you really want for a weight/bonus set of inputs? Expected value? Variance too? Max and min? To 6 digits of accuracy? Run 100k or 1M simulations for each input and number of rolls, calculate the stats you want, and store the results. You'd probably be fine with 10k sims...

Comment: Have you written code for this already? You should include example code that demonstrates the problem if so. Also, you're describing a brute force approach, generating all possible outcomes. Simulating the outcomes something like 10,000 times can give pretty good results for probabilities like this, and scale much better to large numbers of rolls/samples.